# How do i display dynamic content in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]When i click on a button i want to be to open up a modal and in that modal i want to show some data that i am getting from the server.I am using JSON server as a fake server and Materialize css as a css framework.I am only able to open up modal partially and to display part of my data.I don t see any errors in the console.
This is a link to my Github repo:
https://github.com/Ivan3628/IT-logger-js

HTML

```
<ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="#tech-list-modal"
            class="btn-floating green modal-trigger tech-collection"
            ><i class="material-icons">person</i></a
          >
          <!--Tech list modal-->
          <div id="tech-list-modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <h4>Technician List</h4>
              <ul class="collection" id="tech-workers"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
const showTechList = () => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/techs")
    .then(response => ui.showList(response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

document
  .querySelector(".tech-collection")
  .addEventListener("click", showTechList);
```

ui.js

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.techList = document.querySelector("#tech-workers");
  }
 showList(techs) {
    let output = "";

    techs.forEach(tech => {
      output += `
      <li class="collection-item">
      <div>
       ${tech.firstName} ${tech.lastName}
       <a href="#!" class="secondary-content delete-tech" data-id="${tech.id}">
          <i class="material-icons grey-text">delete</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>`;
    });
    this.techList.innerHTML = output;
  }
}

export const ui = new UI();
```

db.json

```
{
"techs": [
    {
      "firstName": "Jennifer",
      "lastName": "Williams",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Sam",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "I am only able to open up modal partially and to display part of my data" Which part you can see? Could you post a screenshot or console.log() it?

Comment: pls add screenshot

Comment: Aye, a desperate need for more info here.

Comment: I am able to open a modal when i click on a button but i am only able to see one of the items and i have three of them on JSON server.Also that item appears above the header and it should be bellow.I posted a link to my Github repo you can download the entire app if you wish and see it for yourself, i ll try to post a screenshot with small resolution as they request here.

Comment: What are you getting in response.data? is it just an array of "techs", or an object with the property "techs", which contains an array? If the latter is the case, i think you should be iterating over response.data.techs, and not response.data

Comment: I think i am getting an array because i am calling techs object (which contains an array) in  my axios call.  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/techs")

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.I think this was perhaps issue with materialize css.Instead of using list to display content i just used row and instead of listed item i used col s12 to loop through data.

html

```
  <!--Technician list-->
          <div id="tech-list-modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <h4>Technician list</h4>
              <div class="row" id="tech-workers"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

ui.js

```
showList(techs) {
    let output = "";

    techs.forEach(tech => {
      output += `
     <div class="col s12">
      ${tech.firstName} ${tech.lastName}
       <a href="#!" class="secondary-content delete-tech" data-id="${tech.id}">
          <i class="material-icons grey-text">delete</i>
        </a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </div>

   `;
    });
    this.techList.innerHTML = output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, there is absolutely no issue with placing ul>li inside a modal in materializcss. A codepen to demonstrate:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/RwPpLZY

We start of with a single empty ul inside the modal:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <ul class="collection" id="tech-workers">
        <!-- no content! -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">x</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To generate dynamic content I have used a select. This could be anything - a database call, local storage, page content - anything. But for this demo it's easy to use a select:

```
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Add 1 item</option>
      <option value="2">Add 2 items</option>
      <option value="3">Add 3 items
    </select>
```

Then, when the select is changed, I pick up the value and use this as a loop to append a new collection-item to the ul, clearing it first so that we have a fresh modal each time.

```
$('select').on('change',function(){

    var selected = Number( $('select').find(":selected").val() );

    $('#tech-workers').empty();

      for(var i=1; i <= selected; i++ ) {
        $('#tech-workers').append(`<li class="collection-item">I am item number ${i}</li>`);
      }

    $('.modal').modal('open');

  });
```